# TF26006: Team Foundation could not find 0

Tags: tfsbuild

We are running some issues with our TFS builds (2012 with update 3). For a team project, all builds are ending up with an error: 
**Exception Message: TF26006: Team Foundation could not find 0. (type DeniedOrNotExistException)**

Symthoms are:

- For other team projects, builds are running fine. There is a problem
  for all builds in a specific team project.
- Builds generate drop artifacts into folder but doesn't update test servers (that's an xcopy operation with powershell command which is triggered after
  build).

So far we have tried to restart our controller and agents. It didn't work out.
Is there anything else we can try?

```
Edit: Full expection stack trace is here:
Exception Message: TF26006: Team Foundation could not find 0. (type DeniedOrNotExistException)
Exception Stack Trace: 
Server stack trace: 
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.ProjectCollection..ctor(WorkItemStore store)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItemStore.get_Projects()
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.FieldDefinitionCollection..ctor(WorkItemStore store, Boolean filtered)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItemStore.get_FieldDefinitions()
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.ClientWiqlAdapterHelper.FindField(String name, String prefix, Object tableTag)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.Wiql.NodeFieldName.Bind(IExternal external, NodeTableName tableContext, NodeFieldName fieldContext)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.Wiql.Node.BindChildren(IExternal external, NodeTableName tableContext, NodeFieldName fieldContext)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.Wiql.NodeFieldList.Bind(IExternal external, NodeTableName tableContext, NodeFieldName fieldContext)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.Wiql.NodeSelect.Bind(IExternal external, NodeTableName tableContext, NodeFieldName fieldContext)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.Query.Initialize(WorkItemStore store, String wiql, IDictionary context, Int32[] ids, Int32[] revs, Boolean dayPrecision)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.Query..ctor(WorkItemStore store, String wiql)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.Activities.WitQueryWorkItems.RunCommand(WorkItemStore workItemStore, IEnumerable`1 ids, IEnumerable`1 fields, Int32 pageSize, Boolean includeParentWorkItems)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Object[]& outArgs)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.AsyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg, IMessageSink replySink)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.EndInvokeHelper(Message reqMsg, Boolean bProxyCase)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RemotingProxy.Invoke(Object NotUsed, MessageData& msgData)
   at System.Func`6.EndInvoke(IAsyncResult result)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.Activities.WitQueryWorkItems.EndExecute(AsyncCodeActivityContext context, IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Activities.AsyncCodeActivity`1.System.Activities.IAsyncCodeActivity.FinishExecution(AsyncCodeActivityContext context, IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Activities.AsyncCodeActivity.CompleteAsyncCodeActivityData.CompleteAsyncCodeActivityWorkItem.Execute(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)
```

Answer (score 9):

Issue was resolved once build server's Team Foundation cache is fully cleaned (You had better stop build services before, so that you won't have to deal with files which are locked).
To do that, i cleaned the ***content*** of folder below:
C:\Users\username(Team Explorer user name)\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\4.0\Cache

Comment: Thanks, I was getting this same error on my local machine when using `witadmin.exe` and deleting everything in `C:\Users\Dan.Schroeder\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation` got it working again.